# The correct way to modify core code - need clarification

Tags: upgrade, best-practice

I'm preparing my installation of 1.8 to upgrade to the latest. Over the past year I've had a few different developers assist me and even though I ask them not to modify core code, some do anyway.

I've done a search for any files modified past the installation date and have come across a few that need to be preserved.

**Question**

If file */code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php* has been modified, my understanding is that to protect this from the upgrade I need to move it */code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php* ?

Is moving modified core code to the **/app/code/local** the correct way to protect modified files from upgrades?

Comment: I think rewriting it is better, what is mean by clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, magento will take the class from the local folder. But it could lead to a wrong magento behavior, because the new version may assume the class has a new methods. And the old version does not have them.

I recommend you run diff command to see the changes an move them into a separate extension class, that extends the core one. This allows to use new features an do not lost the modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, forgot to mention in my question: The same goes for /app/locale any files modified go into the active theme so /app/design/frontend/default/ACTIVE_THEME/local correct?

Comment: For the templates just copy them to the active theme. There is no "local" folder for .phtml files, but for small changes there is local.xml layout.